# Поставить оценку приложению из приложения

Tags: android, google-play

Добрый день.
Раньше неоднократно встречал в приложениях диалоговое окно где пользователь мог поставить оценку приложению не переходя в play маркет. Прошу подскать мне как это делается, и/или в какую сторону копать если сам не смог найти ответ!)
Спасибо!

Comment: Ни разу таких приложений не видел. Попробуйте найти работающий пример.

Comment: Сделайте диалоговое окно со звёздами и принимайте отзывы у себя на сервере. А так из приложения, не заходя в market, нельзя сделать такое, пробовал.

Comment: ЮрийСПб -> Вот пробую найти) не получается) Возможно  iFr0z и прав, и то сбор не для маркета, а свои. Но вроде бы было всетаки для маркета...

Comment: Скорей всего вы встречали такой [функционал](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514579/how-to-implement-rate-it-feature-in-android-app) - попробуйте!

Comment: Ivan Vovk -> Буду вникать, спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

Ivan Vovk указал верное решение (Спасибо ему). Суть проста.

Подключаем `implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'`

Реализовуем метод в классе активности

```
fun askRatings(){
    val manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this)
    val request: Task<ReviewInfo> = manager.requestReviewFlow()
    request.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            val reviewInfo: ReviewInfo = task.result
            val flow: Task<Void> = manager.launchReviewFlow(this, reviewInfo)
            flow.addOnCompleteListener { task2 -> }
        }
    }
}
```

В в нужный момент вызываем его `askRatings()`

ВСЕ!

При чем если пользователь уже отметился, то повторно диалог всплывать не будет.